# Is there a site to see the status of YouTube APIs?

Tags: youtube-api

I noticed today that uploads via the V2 Data API seem to be very slow compared to normal. I was wondering if there is a site that displays system issues and alerts so that we as developers can make sure that issues are known and if not where we can report them?

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/known-issues/16903?hl=en

Comment: I see that the link you provided covers site issues, but doesn't seem to cover API issues.

Answer (score 2):

The status does not appear to be reported anywhere officially. Bugs, downtime, and feature requests (like an API status page ) can be reported via their [issue tracker page](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc).

Comment: I found the link of api-status.com is dead. It seems that api.status.com was closed: https://twitter.com/api_status

Comment: Update: all of those links are now dead or no longer updated, except for the "File an API bug" links.

Comment: Updated answer since original links are now obsolete.